# How can I test oAuth2 in localhost testing environment?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am working with flask application and I want to add login function with Facebook account.
All code work is done but facebook need domain. 
When I used localhost it shows errors.
How can I handle this one?

Answer (score 1):

For my local development with OAuth I get round this type of problem via the hosts file - it also helps me to run a more real world local setup.

Would that work for you?
[developer-domain-setup](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/15/developer-domain-setup/)